# A question on Fourier Transform

Tags: real-analysis, functions, fourier-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Is there a function which is not absolutely integrable but which has a continuous fourier transform?

I know that if a function is absolutely integrable then the fourier transform is continuous but I want to know whether the converse is false. Any help is appreciated . Thanks

Comment: Just a continuous fourier transform, or should  its derivative be continuous too? Because else I can probably construct such a function as the inverse transform of a piecewise-defined function. Just as a hunch, the inverse transform of `|x|` might not be absolutely integratable (I'd have to check).

Comment: @MSalters I took a rect function and then made it continuous and to my surprise the inverse fourier transform  was absolutely integrable as for your example whether inverse seems to have a problem when i put the limits at $\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$ f_n(x) = \cases{ 1 & if $|x|\le n$ \cr
                    0 & if $|x| \ge n+1$ \cr
                    1 + n - |x| & if $n \le |x| \le n + 1 $.\cr } $$
Then I think you should find that $\|\hat {f_n}\|_1 \approx \log n$.  Now try something like
$$ g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^2}f_{2^k}(x) . $$

Then $\hat g = \check g$ is not absolutely integrable, but $g$ is continuous.

Or quote something like the closed graph theorem to get a contradiction from the functions $f_n$.  Sorry, I left a lot of the work for you to do.